# JS/Vue - При использовании директивы v-bind вылетает предупреждение v-bind is not bound

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Не могу понять, с чем связано предупреждение директивы **v-bind**

> Namespace v-bind is not bound*

при использовании для атрибута `title`. `vue.js` скриптовый файл самого vue.

Код:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My first Vue app</title>
    <script src="vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="app-2">
  <span v-bind:title="message">
    Подержи курсор надо мной пару секунд,
    чтобы увидеть динамически связанное значение title!
  </span>
</div>

<script>
        var app2 = new Vue({
            el: '#app-2',
            data: {
                message: 'Вот когда вы загрузили эту страницу: ' + new Date().toLocaleString()
            }
        });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

v-bind имеет упращенный синтаксис.
было -

> v-bind:title

стало

> :title